# Debugging: Tracing (and diff-ing) function call tree of two version of the same program

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, trace, callgrind

I'm working on the rewriting of some
code in a c++ cmd line program.

I
changed the low level data structure that
it uses and the new version passes all
the tests (quite a lot) without any
problem and I get the correct output
from both the new and the old version...
Still, when give certain input, they give
different behaviour.

Getting to the point: Being somewhat of
a big project I don't have a clue about
how to track down when the execution
flow diverges, so... is there way to trace
the function call tree (possibly excluding
std calls) along with, i don't know, line
number in the source file and source
name?
Maybe some gcc or macro kungfu?

I would need a Linux solution since that's where the program runs.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to print the call stack when control reaches a certain point (i.e. adding code to output the current stack), or are you looking for an external tool to analyze your program flow as it runs (basically callgrind's manpage)?

Comment: I've used callgrind before, but, if I remember, it only outputs the number of time a function gets called and the relationships between functions (and other stuff too, but it discards the program history). I could well be wrong since I only used it through KCachegrind.
I need something that "simply" outputs function names and where they are called from as the execution flows. Like ltrace but for my code, not library calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Still, when give certain input, they give different behaviour

I would expand logging in you old and new versions in order to understand better work of your algorithms for `certain input`. When it become clearer you can for example use gdb if you still need it.

**Update**
OK, As for me logging is OK, but you do not want to add it.

Another method is tracing. Actually I used it only on Solaris but I see that it exists also on Linux. I have not used it on Linux so it is just an idea that you can test.

You can use [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap//SystemTap_Beginners_Guide.pdf)

> **User-Space Probing** 
> SystemTap initially focused on kernel-space probing. However, there are many instances where userspace probing can
>   help diagnose a problem. SystemTap 0.6 added support to allow probing
>   userspace processes. SystemTap includes support for probing the entry
>   into and return from a function in user-space processes, probing
>   predefined markers in user-space code, and monitoring user-process
>   events.

I can gurantee that it will work but why don't give it a try?

There is even an example in the doc:

> If you want to see how the function xmalloc function is being called
>   by the command ls, you could use the user-space backtrack functions to
>   provide that information.

```
stap -d /bin/ls --ldd \
-e 'probe process("ls").function("xmalloc") {print_ustack(ubacktrace())}' \
-c "ls /"
```

Comment: I thought about that, but I just can't go here and there adding logging messages throughout the code.

Comment: @3mpty, these "user space probes" are based on software breakpoints. You just need to build your program with debug info and provide a white or black list of function names.

Comment: Thanks :) I got a basic trace log using the simple stuff at https://github.com/creechley/etrace but it's more an hack than something serious
I'll try systemtrap to see if I can get better results.